# Next deployment fails only on Amplify

Tags: build, next.js, aws-amplify, vercel, swc-compiler

I am trying to deploy Next.js app on AWS Amplify but it keep fails.
Build worked perfectly fine in local environment and I even succeeded to deploy on Vercel.
But it only fails on Amplify :(

I was able to deploy by creating a `.babelrc` file, but I am looking for a better solution of keeping SWC.

I tried:

- `rm package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall (`npm install --force`)
- Install `@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu` and `@next/swc-linux-x64-musl` as optionalDependencies
- Set `swcMinify` option to `false` in `next.config.js`
- Remove `compiler` option in `next.config.js`

**▼ Environment**

```
v16.13.2 x64 linux
```

**▼ `package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "framer-motion": "^6.4.3",
    "next": "12.2.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.1",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "recoil": "^0.7.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "twemoji": "^14.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
    "eslint": "8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

**▼ `next.config.js`**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })
    return config
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: {
      displayName: true,
      ssr: true,
    },
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**▼ Error logs**

```
                                                                  # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: nvm use --lts
2022-07-13T23:48:13.094Z [INFO]: Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
2022-07-13T23:48:13.095Z [INFO]: # Executing command: node -e 'console.log(process.version, process.arch, process.platform)'
2022-07-13T23:48:13.122Z [INFO]: v16.13.2 x64 linux
2022-07-13T23:48:13.125Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci --include=optional
2022-07-13T23:48:20.109Z [WARNING]: npm
2022-07-13T23:48:20.111Z [WARNING]: WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
2022-07-13T23:48:27.374Z [INFO]: added 508 packages, and audited 509 packages in 14s
2022-07-13T23:48:27.377Z [INFO]: 100 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
                                 found 0 vulnerabilities
2022-07-13T23:48:27.389Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
2022-07-13T23:48:27.389Z [INFO]: # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2022-07-13T23:48:27.663Z [INFO]: > my-project@0.1.0 build
                                 > next build
2022-07-13T23:48:28.057Z [INFO]: info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
2022-07-13T23:48:28.065Z [INFO]: warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
2022-07-13T23:48:28.086Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2022-07-13T23:48:28.086Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
                                 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
                                 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2022-07-13T23:48:28.174Z [INFO]: info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
2022-07-13T23:48:33.726Z [INFO]: info  - Creating an optimized production build...
2022-07-13T23:48:34.350Z [INFO]: info  - Downloading WASM swc package...
2022-07-13T23:48:35.445Z [INFO]: info  - Using experimental wasm build of next-swc
2022-07-13T23:48:35.613Z [WARNING]: warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but an error occurred: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-07-13T23:48:35.614Z [WARNING]: warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnux32, but it was not installed
                                    warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but an error occurred: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-07-13T23:48:48.873Z [WARNING]: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: IOError(Error { kind: Unsupported, message: "operation not supported on this platform" }) }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
                                    Stack:
                                    Error
                                    at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/codebuild/output/src358588912/src/my-project/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
2022-07-13T23:48:48.911Z [WARNING]: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
                                    Stack:
                                    Error
                                    at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/codebuild/output/src358588912/src/my-project/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
2022-07-13T23:48:49.415Z [WARNING]: Failed to compile.
                                    static/chunks/pages/_app-8aa2b8cf1034125e.js from Terser
                                    unreachable
                                    RuntimeError: unreachable
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186aff
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x760098
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
                                    static/chunks/framework-a1d4bfd54c97f1bc.js from Terser
                                    unreachable
                                    RuntimeError: unreachable
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x760098
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
                                    at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
2022-07-13T23:48:49.417Z [WARNING]: 
2022-07-13T23:48:49.417Z [WARNING]: > Build failed because of webpack errors
2022-07-13T23:48:49.456Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-07-13T23:48:49.457Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-07-13T23:48:49.457Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-07-13T23:48:49.457Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2022-07-13T23:48:49.532Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Comment: So I just ran into this same error message but was doing a local build, to test out some stuff with my cms. I reinstalled node modules and then the error went away. Since my code base was stable I assumed it was an error with the node module package containing the wasm file  I reinstalled node modules to get the latest updates of the packages. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade nextjs version to 12.2.0 and should work fine!!
Detail here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38436

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the SwcMinify or the TypeScript plugins.

I had the same issue and I disabled SwcMinify and edited the TypeScript plugins in `.eslintrc.json`.

```
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
"extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to solve it, I had to delete completely the **node_modules** folder and reinstall all packages with **yarn install**.