# Building error while deploying to AWS amplify

Tags: webpack, next.js, aws-amplify, build-error

I tried to deploy fresh, unchanged repo of nextjs-graphcommerce,(https://github.com/graphcommerce-org/graphcommerce.git),

and I followed their documentation to clone, and develop in the local environment.

it works fine in the local environment but when I try to deploy to AWS amplify i get this error:

```
    # Starting phase: preBuild
    # Executing command: yarn install
```

..........

```
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript@2.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript-generic-sdk@2.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript-generic-sdk@2.3.13" has unmet peer dependency "graphql-tag@^2.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations@2.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript-resolvers@2.6.7" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.832Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/graphql-mesh > @graphql-mesh/config@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@graphql-mesh/runtime@^0.41.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/runtime@0.41.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/store@0.8.20" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/string-interpolation@0.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.832Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-tools/wrap@8.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > graphql-import-node@0.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > graphql-ws@5.9.1" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@>=0.11 <=16".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > ts-node@10.8.2" has unmet peer dependency "@types/node@".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/types > @graphql-tools/delegate@8.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/types > @graphql-typed-document-node/core@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > @graphql-codegen/core > @graphql-tools/schema@8.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > @graphql-tools/code-file-loader > @graphql-tools/graphql-tag-pluck@7.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > @graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader > @graphql-tools/import@6.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > @graphql-tools/prisma-loader > graphql-request@4.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@14 - 16".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > @graphql-tools/url-loader > @n1ru4l/graphql-live-query@0.9.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^15.4.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-codegen/cli > graphql-config > @graphql-tools/merge@8.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typed-document-node > @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common@2.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.8.0 || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.833Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typescript-operations > @graphql-codegen/typescript@2.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.834Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @envelop/core@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @graphql-mesh/cache-localforage@0.6.17" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @graphql-mesh/merger-bare@0.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @graphql-mesh/merger-stitching@0.16.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/cross-helpers > react-native-fs@2.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.834Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/runtime > @envelop/extended-validation@1.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/runtime > @graphql-tools/batch-delegate@8.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/store > @graphql-inspector/core@3.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.834Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-yoga/node > @graphql-yoga/common@2.12.3" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^15.2.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/types > @graphql-tools/delegate > @graphql-tools/batch-execute@8.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.834Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typed-document-node > @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common > @graphql-tools/optimize@1.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typed-document-node > @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common > @graphql-tools/relay-operation-optimizer@6.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.835Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @envelop/core > @envelop/types@2.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.835Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @graphql-mesh/merger-stitching > @graphql-tools/stitch@8.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-mesh/config > @graphql-mesh/merger-stitching > @graphql-tools/stitching-directives@2.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.835Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-yoga/node > @graphql-yoga/common > @envelop/parser-cache@4.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-yoga/node > @graphql-yoga/common > @envelop/validation-cache@4.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/cli > @graphql-mesh/cli > @graphql-codegen/typed-document-node > @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common > @graphql-tools/relay-operation-optimizer > @ardatan/relay-compiler@12.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@*".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.835Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/next-config > @lingui/loader > @lingui/cli > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.18.6" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.836Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/next-ui > @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.18.6" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.836Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui@1.1.3" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.837Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/next-ui@4.14.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.838Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/graphql > @graphcommerce/graphql-codegen-near-operation-file@3.0.15" has unmet peer dependency "@graphql-tools/utils@^8.6.2".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.841Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/next-ui > @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop@11.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.842Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/framer-next-pages@3.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "@emotion/react@^11.8.2".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.842Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/framer-scroller@2.1.24" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
warning " > @graphcommerce/framer-scroller@2.1.24" has unmet peer dependency "popmotion@11.0.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.842Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/image@3.1.7" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.843Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/graphql > @graphcommerce/graphql-codegen-relay-optimizer-plugin > relay-compiler@12.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^15.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.844Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/next-ui > @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop > @emotion/babel-plugin@11.9.2" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
warning "@graphcommerce/ecommerce-ui > @graphcommerce/next-ui > @emotion/babel-preset-css-prop > @emotion/babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic@0.1.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.844Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/googlerecaptcha@2.1.12" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.844Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/graphcms-ui@3.0.31" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.846Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/lingui-next@2.1.11" has unmet peer dependency "make-plural@^6.2.2".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.846Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart@4.6.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.846Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-customer@4.8.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.846Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-customer@4.8.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql@16.5.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.847Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-store@4.2.18" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.848Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-billing-address@3.0.36" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-checkout@3.0.38" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-coupon@3.1.6" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.848Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-items@3.0.39" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.848Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-product@4.4.16" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.848Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-email@3.0.38" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.849Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-payment-method@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.849Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-payment-method@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^17.0.1".
warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-payment-method@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.1".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.849Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-pickup@3.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.849Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-shipping-method@3.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.850Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cart-shipping-address@3.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.850Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-category@4.1.24" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.850Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-cms@4.0.29" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.850Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-customer-account@3.1.31" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.851Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-customer-order@3.0.32" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.851Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-newsletter@2.0.36" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.851Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-payment-braintree@3.0.37" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.852Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-payment-included@3.1.9" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.854Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-product-configurable@4.1.23" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.855Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-review@3.2.24" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.855Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/magento-search@4.1.26" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.858Z [WARNING]: warning " > @graphcommerce/mollie-magento-payment@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "@mui/material@5.5.3".
warning " > @graphcommerce/mollie-magento-payment@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^17.0.1".
warning " > @graphcommerce/mollie-magento-payment@3.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^17.0.1".
warning " > @graphcommerce/next-config@3.1.6" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.70.0".
warning " > @lingui/cli@3.14.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.858Z [WARNING]: warning " > @lingui/cli@3.14.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-plugin-macros@2 || 3".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.859Z [WARNING]: warning "next-pwa > terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^5.1.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.861Z [WARNING]: warning "next-pwa > babel-loader@8.2.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.861Z [WARNING]: warning "next-pwa > babel-loader@8.2.5" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2".
warning "next-pwa > clean-webpack-plugin@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=4.0.0 <6.0.0".
warning "next-pwa > workbox-webpack-plugin@6.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.4.0 || ^5.9.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.865Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/eslint-config-pwa > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.13.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=1.11.0".
2022-07-26T02:48:26.867Z [WARNING]: warning "@graphcommerce/prettier-config-pwa > prettier-plugin-jsdoc@0.3.38" has unmet peer dependency "prettier@>=2.1.2".
2022-07-26T02:48:37.100Z [INFO]: [5/5] Building fresh packages...
2022-07-26T02:48:39.280Z [INFO]: Done in 42.80s.
2022-07-26T02:48:39.306Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
# Starting phase: build
# Executing command: yarn run build
2022-07-26T02:48:39.436Z [INFO]: yarn run v1.22.0
2022-07-26T02:48:39.481Z [INFO]: $ mesh build && graphql-codegen && next build && next-sitemap
2022-07-26T02:48:40.410Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mCleaning existing artifacts�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:40.420Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mReading the configuration�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:41.451Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mGenerating the unified schema�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:50.943Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mGenerating artifacts�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:50.947Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mGenerating index file in TypeScript�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:51.962Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mWriting index.ts for CJS to the disk.�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:51.977Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mCleanup�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:51.977Z [INFO]: bulb �[1mspider_web Mesh�[0m �[36mDone! => /codebuild/output/src828351655/src/nxtmgt/.mesh�[0m
2022-07-26T02:48:52.675Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Parse Configuration
2022-07-26T02:48:52.676Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Parse Configuration
2022-07-26T02:48:52.676Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Generate outputs
2022-07-26T02:48:52.677Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Generate node_modules/@graphcommerce/graphql/generated/types.ts
2022-07-26T02:48:52.678Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Load GraphQL schemas
2022-07-26T02:48:54.624Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Load GraphQL schemas
2022-07-26T02:48:54.625Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Load GraphQL documents
[SUCCESS] Load GraphQL documents
[STARTED] Generate
2022-07-26T02:48:54.641Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate
2022-07-26T02:48:54.641Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate node_modules/@graphcommerce/graphql/generated/types.ts
[STARTED] Generate node_modules/@graphcommerce/graphql/generated/fragments.json
2022-07-26T02:48:54.642Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Load GraphQL schemas
[SUCCESS] Load GraphQL schemas
[STARTED] Load GraphQL documents
[SUCCESS] Load GraphQL documents
[STARTED] Generate
2022-07-26T02:48:54.680Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate
2022-07-26T02:48:54.680Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate node_modules/@graphcommerce/graphql/generated/fragments.json
[STARTED] Generate to . (using EXPERIMENTAL preset "@graphcommerce/graphql-codegen-near-operation-file")
[STARTED] Load GraphQL schemas
2022-07-26T02:48:54.681Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Load GraphQL schemas
[STARTED] Load GraphQL documents
2022-07-26T02:48:54.846Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Load GraphQL documents
2022-07-26T02:48:54.847Z [INFO]: [STARTED] Generate
2022-07-26T02:49:08.794Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate
2022-07-26T02:49:08.795Z [INFO]: [SUCCESS] Generate to . (using EXPERIMENTAL preset "@graphcommerce/graphql-codegen-near-operation-file")
[SUCCESS] Generate outputs
2022-07-26T02:49:10.032Z [WARNING]: {"type":"warning","data":"Resolution field "cross-undici-fetch@0.4.13" is incompatible with requested version "cross-undici-fetch@0.4.11""}
2022-07-26T02:49:10.643Z [WARNING]: warn - You have enabled experimental features (scrollRestoration, browsersListForSwc, legacyBrowsers) in next.config.js.
2022-07-26T02:49:10.644Z [WARNING]: warn - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
2022-07-26T02:49:10.644Z [INFO]: info - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
2022-07-26T02:49:10.668Z [INFO]: Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2022-07-26T02:49:10.669Z [INFO]: This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2022-07-26T02:49:10.759Z [INFO]: info - Skipping linting
2022-07-26T02:49:10.760Z [INFO]: info - Checking validity of types...
2022-07-26T02:50:08.290Z [INFO]: info - Creating an optimized production build...
2022-07-26T02:50:08.446Z [INFO]: info - Downloading WASM swc package...
2022-07-26T02:50:10.027Z [INFO]: info - Using experimental wasm build of next-swc
2022-07-26T02:50:10.119Z [WARNING]: warn - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but an error occurred: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-07-26T02:50:10.119Z [WARNING]: warn - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnux32, but it was not installed
warn - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but an error occurred: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-07-26T02:50:10.784Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Compile client (static)
2022-07-26T02:50:10.785Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Auto register service worker with: /codebuild/output/src828351655/src/nxtmgt/node_modules/next-pwa/register.js
> [PWA] Service worker: /codebuild/output/src828351655/src/nxtmgt/public/sw.js
2022-07-26T02:50:10.785Z [INFO]: > [PWA] url: /sw.js
> [PWA] scope: /
2022-07-26T02:50:11.453Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Compile server
2022-07-26T02:50:11.477Z [INFO]: > [PWA] Compile server
2022-07-26T02:51:18.868Z [WARNING]: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: IOError(Error { kind: Unsupported, message: "operation not supported on this platform" }) }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
Stack:
Error
at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/codebuild/output/src828351655/src/nxtmgt/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)
at :wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
at :wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
2022-07-26T02:51:19.180Z [WARNING]: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
Stack:
Error
at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/codebuild/output/src828351655/src/nxtmgt/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)
at :wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
at :wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
2022-07-26T02:51:27.370Z [WARNING]: Failed to compile.
2022-07-26T02:51:27.372Z [WARNING]: static/chunks/pages/_app-747ba0654694bb1d.js from Terser
unreachable
RuntimeError: unreachable
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186aff
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
at :wasm-function[654]:0x760098
at :wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
static/chunks/7240.460e98a224fe6648.js from Terser
unreachable
RuntimeError: unreachable
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
at :wasm-function[654]:0x760098
at :wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
static/chunks/framework-e9dfcd1e2bd125d0.js from Terser
unreachable
RuntimeError: unreachable
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
at :wasm-function[654]:0x760098
at :wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
static/chunks/638014a0-1656a1bcbf90e945.js from Terser
unreachable
RuntimeError: unreachable
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[9251]:0x1157722
at :wasm-function[9251]:0x11576aa
at :wasm-function[9251]:0x11576aa
at :wasm-function[1392]:0xa4bb66
at :wasm-function[71]:0x23800d
static/chunks/1397-9b7a9a963a9cd85f.js from Terser
unreachable
RuntimeError: unreachable
at :wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
at :wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
at :wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
at :wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
at :wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
at :wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
at :wasm-function[654]:0x760098
at :wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
at :wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
2022-07-26T02:51:27.373Z [WARNING]:
2022-07-26T02:51:27.373Z [WARNING]: > Build failed because of webpack errors
2022-07-26T02:51:27.456Z [WARNING]: error Command failed with exit code 1.
2022-07-26T02:51:27.456Z [INFO]: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2022-07-26T02:51:27.461Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-07-26T02:51:27.461Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-07-26T02:51:27.462Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-07-26T02:51:27.462Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
2022-07-26T02:51:27.461Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2022-07-26T02:51:27.462Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2022-07-26T02:51:27.462Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, "operation not supported on this platform", so there is a command that can't run on Linux, but it runs on Windows.

There are many solutions to this, the one worked for me is disabling **swcMinify** in **next.config.js**

A possible duplicate for this question:
[Next deployment fails only on Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974024/next-deployment-fails-only-on-amplify)